# Permutations of Numbers with Specific Order Constraints

Tags: combinatorics

> How many are the permutations of the numbers $(1,2,..., 10)$ in which
> 5 is located to the right of 2 and to the left of 3, although not
> necessarily in consecutive places?

Assuming that $S$ was the position of the numbers (1, 3, 6,...,10) and $P_i$, $i=1,2,...,6$ are the possible positions of (2, 5, 3), since we have the permutation $3!=6$ of (2, 5, 3). For example, $P_1$ are all the possible permutations of (1, 2, ....,10) where there is only the order (3, 2, 5). Assuming that the positions that have an order different from $2-5-3$ are considered as repetitions of "wrong" orders. As the total number of permutations is $10!$ with repetition of 6 (total number of permutations of the wrong orders), we will have $\frac{10!}{6!}$. I would like to know if this is a correct way to think about the solution.

Another way I thought was: we have an arrangement $\frac{10!}{(10-3)!}$ to dispose $2, 5, 3$ among the $10$ positions (since order matters), so it follows $\frac{10!}{(10-3)!} \cdot 7!$. But this is not the answer.... what is the flaw in this reasoning?

Comment: 1/ How many non "2, 3, 5" numbers are there? You seem to indicate 6 via "$i = 1, 2, ...6$"? Can you check? $\quad$ 2/ How many repetition of "wrong" orders are there? You seem to indicate 6!? Can you elaborate? $\quad$ The idea of "reduce by repetition of wrong orders" is good, but you might have introduced several typos (or they could be conceptual errors).

Comment: As @CalvinLin's comment indicates, your analysis is almost perfect.  The elements $~\{2,3,5\}~$ can be *permuted* in $~3!~$ different ways, rather than $~6!~$ different ways, so the desired computation is $~\displaystyle \frac{10!}{\color{red}{3!}}.$

Comment: As @user2661923 writes, the answer is $\frac{10!}{3!}$. And another way to see that is to consider that if you first ignore 2, 3, and 5 and simply arrange the others, there are $7!$ ways to do that. And for each of those, you can then decide where to insert the three holdouts, which, by stars and bars, can be done in ${{7+3}\choose 3}=\frac{10\times9\times8}{3!}$ ways. Multiply those and you get the answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin I've edited my text, I hope you understand now

Answer (score 2):

> Another way I thought was: we have an arrangement $\frac{10!}{(10-3)!}$ to dispose $2, 5, 3$ among the $10$ positions (since order matters), so it follows $\frac{10!}{(10-3)!} \cdot 7!$. But this is not the answer.... what is the flaw in this reasoning?

Consider the following tableau:

```
1 _ 4 _ 5 6 7 8 9 _ 10
```

There are $~\displaystyle \frac{10!}{3!}~$ ways of ordering the elements $~\{1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}~$ among the $~10~$ available positions, leaving three positions open, for the remaining elements $~\{2,3,5\}.$  Therefore, there are $~\displaystyle \frac{10!}{3!}~$ *potentially satisfying tableaus*.

For each such *tableau*, there is **exactly** one satisfying way of then positioning the three remaining elements, $~\{2,3,5\},~$ into the three remaining slots.

Therefore, the answer must be $~\displaystyle \frac{10!}{3!}.$

Comment: FWIW OP has a lot of either typos or conceptual errors, so it's not clear to me if your writeup is that helpful without addressing those. EG In the quoted text, how did they arrive at $10! / 7! \times 7! = 10!$ as the answer?

Comment: @CalvinLin Agreed; it is also unclear to me whether my response helped.  The most that I can say is that prior to my response, the OP's "where did I go wrong" trailing issue had not yet been addressed, and that my response *might* be helpful to him.  Personally, I share your confusion as to whether $~10!/7! \times 7!~$ is typo driven or a conceptual error.  My standard approach in such a situation is to simply light the lamp and hope that the OP will ask questions, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have badly mixed up typos and confusing terminology to come to grief !

In the first para, you have  brought in $P_i$ having $6$ **positions**, whereas you mean $6$ permutations, and after correctly stating that $(2,5,3)$ have $6$ permutations, the answer should be $\color{blue} 
  {\frac{10!}{6}}$, alternatively $\color{blue}{ \frac{10!}{3!}}$ but whether as a typo or some misconception, you have given the answer as $\color{red}{\frac{10!}{6!}}$

And in the second para,  you are correctly multiplying by $7!$ for the unrestricted numbers, *but haven't divided by* $3!$ to take into account that the $3$ "special" numbers are to occur in only one correct order,
so the answer would be $\frac{10!}{7!3!}\times 7!$ to again simplify to $\frac{10!}{3!}$

We create permutations by multiplication, reduce unwanted permutations by the reverse operation of  division, so the direct and simple answer to the problem is $\frac{10!}{3!}$